# In an asynchronous ASP.NET Web API with a lot of traffic, what is the impact of setting ConfigureAwait false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on a new `API` that will eventually receive a very large amount of traffic. I was initially under the impression that I'd want to set `ConfigureAwait(false)` through my full `async`/`await` stack, but after attempting to debug some `application insights` `tracing` I found out that certain values in the `HttpContext` are lost if I use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Can anybody with some high traffic `API` experience tell me anything else I might be missing that could be impacted by having `ConfigureAwait(false)` like is it possible for a user to receive the output from a different user's request?

What would be the impact of removing all `ConfigureAwait(false)` statements in my `API`?

Comment: "Is it possible for a user to receive the output from a different user's request" would be a HUGE bug. And i don't believe ConfigureAwait breaks that. I don't know what kind of definitive answer you're looking for, but AFAIK .ConfigureAwait(false) is pretty much best practice for webapi unless you have some special thread affinity cases (which is unlikely)

Comment: There's nothing in my code that would allow a user to get somebody else's reponse, but because I lost some values in the HttpContext after an async call I kind of saw that as a red flag.

Comment: Well it's logical, without the configure(false) it needs to keep extra information to maintain thread affinity - which can then be purged with the configure. If you're still concerned, i'd suggest digging into exactly what is getting removed.

Answer (score 5):

> is it possible for a user to receive the output from a different user's request?

Realistically, no.  Certainly this wouldn't happen *just* by adding `ConfigureAwait(false)`.  You'd need to pretty explicitly pass data from one request to another to do this.

> What would be the impact of removing all ConfigureAwait(false) statements in my API?

That API cannot access any information about the current request, because as far as it'd be concerned, there would be no current request. For an API this would be desirable.  The UI specific code would interact with the current request to provide the input to the API, and would be able to update the request with the results of the API calls, but the API itself wouldn't be interacting with the request.

That is, unless  your API is specifically designed to be a UI API, and it's designed with the expressed purpose of interacting with the current request, in which case, you don't want to explicitly remove the information about the current request with `ConfigureAwait(false)`.